Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"clear\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Cart\"" }
I'm developing an e-commerce application using Express.js, Mongoose, and MongoDB. I'm facing an issue when trying to clear a user's cart. The goal is to delete all items in the cart for the currently authenticated user. However, I keep encountering the following error message:
Context

Backend Framework: Node.js with Express
Database: MongoDB with Mongoose ORM
Authentication: JWT

Problem Description
I have a clearCart function in my cart controller that is supposed to delete all cart items for the logged-in user. The user ID is extracted from the JWT token using middleware.
Relevant Code
cartController.js
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const Cart = require('../models/cartModel');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const clearCart = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("User in clearCart controller:", req.user);

        if (!req.user) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: "Not authorized, user not found" });
            return;
        }

        const userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id);
        console.log("User ID:", userId);
        await Cart.deleteMany({ user: userId });
        console.log("Cart cleared for user:", userId);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Cart cleared' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error clearing cart:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

module.exports = { clearCart }; ```

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        productId: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            ref: "BookUpload",
        },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: "User",
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const Cart = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema);

module.exports = Cart;





You did not provide your error message.share it

Can you console.log(req.user) because you are somehow getting the word clear where you think there should be an ObjectId. Mongoose can't cast the word clear to an ObjectId in order to do your query so it's throwing an error.

i am getting re.user._id in my console and no error in my console

Did the error message include a file name and line number?
